# Редактор Excel страниц в web

Tags: windows

Добрый день. Вот такая история. У меня в организации есть у каждого работника файл Excel который они открывают и работают с ним. Недавно этот файл до того увеличился что на старых ПК он открывается или сохраняется по пол часа. Тем более при редактировании периодически подвисает.

Вот интересно возможно ли сделать что то типа как у google docs? Редактирование таблиц через веб браузер ? У пользователей установлен O.O.

Comment: а почему нельзя его загрузить в гуглдокс?Хотя, конечно нужно описать структуру данных, спроектировать интерфейс и реализовать это в чём-то типа php(html)+mysql.. но это всё моё имхо, возможно есть готовые решения получше.

Comment: @ArcherGodsonс, языка сорвал)))

Comment: Добрый день. В гугл докс загрузить не могу, узкий канал в интернет. В интернете таких готовых решений не могу найти.

Comment: Я так понимаю вот то что меня интересует http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_content_management

Comment: ХМ... если я правильно понял - у вас все равно пользователь будет подгружать ВЕСЬ документ (кста - гуглДокс, скорее всего, тоже). В этом случае цель (ускорение открытия/сохранения на старых РС) достигнуто НЕ будет.Но могу ошибаться:)

Comment: Эксель на ПК у пользователей виснит как раз таки в основном при фильтровке или поиске. Подгружать весь документ они не будут, в основном они работают с поиском и фильтрацией. В опен офисе открывается весь документ и он жутко тормозит при фильтрации или изменении чего либа там. Да и при временном авто сохранении документа.

Comment: Я пробовал сделать такую штуку - выгрузил экселевский файл в mysql а потом открыл им интерфейс в phpmyadmin. Но им не понравился интерфейс и они уперлись рогами.

Comment: Бывает))) я тож сначала напрямую из базы дергал. По поводу скорости... В предложенном мной варианте все вычисления будут производиться на стороне сервера, соответственно Впрочем, думаю, что попробовать ЕСМ тоже можно;) Я вот уже собрался))))

Answer (score 1):

Возникала у меня подобная задача. В результате было принято решение отойти от таблиц ВООБЩЕ.

Методом проб и ошибок был получен результат: внутренний сайт, на котором каждая строка бывшей таблицы - нода (статья, материал .....); настроены представления, в которых пользователи видят данные. Работают уже пол-года - полет нормальный.

Плюсы:

1. познакомился с [CMS/CMF Drupal](http://drupal.org)
2. получил премию
3. наконец-то пользователи могут работать ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬ одновременно
4. файло не уходит за пределы интра-сети
5. не кушается канал/трафик

Минусы:

1. заболел [CMS/CMF Drupal](http://drupal.org)
2. жена гонит искать новую работу.;)

Если интересно, одна из версий (**незавершенная**) лежит [ТУТ](https://github.com/zerglyn/office-minsk)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не совсем то что бы хотелось как на гугл докс но посмотрю)

Comment: Если я правильно понял - принципиален внешний вид, так? Не вопрос, представление можно выводить в таблице... Кроме того, есть модули для экспорта в xls/pdf/....А реализовать функционал GoogleDocs одному в сжатые сроки... Да даже если и не одному, все равно мне представляется не особо реальным...ИМХО

Comment: Ну в общем принципиален внешний вид. Пользователи привыкшие к экселю не поймут. В принципе я нашел нашел некоторые похожие темы http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_content_management

Comment: Первая рабочая версия с "таблицами" лежит [ТУТ][1][1]: https://github.com/zerglyn/drupal.test

Comment: Чем закончилось-то? Интересно же...:)

Comment: Добрый день. Нашел вот только такой убогий вариант http://www.softwaregarden.com/products/wikicalc/

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice via web](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Using_LibreOffice_in_a_Web_Browser)

Пробовал, работает, но с косяками. Но они характерны в основном для каких то исключительных особенностей.

Comment: Так и не получилось запустить его. Как в инструкции написано запускаю с ключами а консоль пишет что не может открыть X интерфейс. X не стоят. Или L.O. нужно ставить с нуля?

Answer (score 1):

А если Office 365 попробовать?

Comment: У нас только СПО.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/45768)

Comment: @tutankhamun вопрос - решение для совместного редактирования **Excel**-файлов. Использование Office 365 - 100% корректное и рабочее решение.

Comment: @PashaPash Ну тогда и писать его стоит как ответ, а не как вопрос

Comment: @tutankhamun Это назвается риторический вопрос -  утверждение, высказанное в вопросительной форме.